# Typescript - bracket index into object does not yield error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm finding that TypeScript is letting me use bracket notation to access an object via index, when it only has keys. For instance:

```
interface testObject {
    name: string;
    id: number;
}

let first: testObject = {name: "Marquizzo", id: 1};

let second = first[1]; // <-- Should yield error!
```

`first[1]` should give me an error because `1` is not defined as a valid key in the `testObject` interface. Is there a flag that I can turn on to avoid this from happening?

Comment: yes, this error is reported with `--noImplicitAny`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have the `noImplicitAny` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) set to `true`.

With that option set to `false` no error is effected, but if it's set to `true` an error is effected:

```
[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'testObject' has no index signature.
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is a double-edge sword then, because if I wanted to do something like `let keyName = "name"; let second = first[keyName];` in my example above, then that would also be disallowed.

Comment: Have a look at the `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` option, before you despair.